# Cannot inject one app module into another AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, code-injection

I have an Angular App consisting of two modules (two pages), one is login and the other rest of the application.

So that I have the following on my login.js file :

```
var app = angular.module('morpheuslogin', ['ngRoute']);
```

Now on my other module (which works perfectly on its own) I try to inject this first module, like this:

```
var morpheusApp = angular.module('morpheusApp', ['ngRoute', 'morpheuslogin']);
```

Now when I start my application i get the following when loading the **morpheusApp** module.

Failed to instantiate module morpheusApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=m...)

I understand that injection can also be applied between modules. These two modules are on different js files, and on different folders within my **public/** folder on my project.

What's in going on here?
What's the best practice on this case?

Thank you.!

Comment: did you include angular-route.js? Show your script tags

Answer (score 0):

No need to inject ngRoute two times in two modules, have it only in the parent module,

```
angular.module('morpheuslogin',[]);
```

Parent Module will be

```
var morpheusApp = angular.module('morpheusApp', ['ngRoute', 'morpheuslogin']);
```

Comment: this won't work as shown, there is no module declaration for `morpheuslogin`

Comment: why its there over top

Comment: no...without second argument that is a getter...not setter